# how to read json file properly with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Getting Error

error TS2732: Cannot find module '../service-
.json'. Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json
sion.

```
import serviceAccountPlay from '../service-account.json';
```

I have this module
file name -> typing.d.ts

```
   declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
      }
```

tsconfig.json

```
   tsconfig.json
   {
      "compilerOptions": {
     "module": "commonjs",
"noImplicitReturns": true,
"noUnusedLocals": false,
"outDir": "lib",
"sourceMap": true,
"strict": false,
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,


 "target": "es2017"
  },
 "compileOnSave": true,
 "include": [
  "src"
  ]
  }
```

Comment: Per [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25400), try enabling `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` in your tsconfig.json

Answer (score 0):

If you see this error `error TS2732: Cannot find module '../service-.json'. Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json.` and modify  your tsconfig.json the changes might not get reloaded.

Quick Fix: Restart VSCode (or whatever IDE you are using). You do not need to modify any other options